# How to know the y position of the Clicked Itemin a listview with regard to the screen in android

Tags: android, listview, webview, long-press

In my application i am inflating a web view into a list view and have set long press click event to the web view. On long press i am duplicating a item to appear on the list view. as shown in the image.

I want to know the clicked item position so that i can make the duplicate view appear exactly above the clicked item, but now it appears on the first item in the list.

the item in grey is the duplicated item, i have clicked on the 10th item and it appears on the 1st item. how would i make it appear on the 10th item
 ![enter image description here][1]

```
wv.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                duplicateView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Log.d("lvsectionTwo "+lvsectionTwo.getScrollY(),"log");
                WebView wv = (WebView) duplicateView.findViewById(R.id.wv1);
                wv.loadData("item "+position, "text/html", null);
                wv.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);

                ![enter image description here][2]



                return true;
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: which adapter do your list use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the y position of view by:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationInWindow%28int[]%29

it would require an array of integer of length 2
and x, and y co-ordinates would be stored in that array object, now use that object to get Position of view

private OnItemLongClickListener onlongpressed = new OnItemLongClickListener() {

```
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
                    duplicateView = ((LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(
                                    LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.dragview, null);
                    frlayout.addView(duplicateView);
                    int[] dimensions=new int[2];
                    getLocationInWindow (dimensions);
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = frlayout.getLayoutParams();
                    layoutParams.setMargins(0, dimensions[1]-20, 0, 0);
                    duplicateView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    duplicateView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    WebView wv = (WebView) duplicateView.findViewById(R.id.wv1);
                    wv.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
                    wv.loadData("Item "+position, "text/html", null);
                    return true;
            }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I would think all you would do is insert the element into the underlying data structure that your adapter operates on at the appropriate place.  Instead of OnLongClickListener, I'd use OnItemLongClickListener though, since it gives you position:

```
getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
        // add something to your structure at (position - 1) and refresh your ListView.
    }
}
```